# Unable to check if thrown error is an instance of a custom error class

Tags: typescript, instanceof

I have created a custom error class which extends the built-in `Error` class and adds a new value to it. The error itself works as expected.

I want to handle this error explicitly when I catch it.

This is my custom error class:

```
export default class CustomHttpError extends Error {
  constructor(readonly httpCode: number, readonly message: string) {
    super(message);

    this.name = 'CustomHttpError';
  }
}
```

This is how I am trying to test it:

```
const CustomHttpError = require('./lib/src/errors/CustomHttpError');

try {
  throw new CustomHttpError(420, 'Enhance Your Calm');
} catch (e) {
  if (e instanceof CustomHttpError) {
    console.log(CustomHttpError.httpCode);
  }
}
```

I receive this error:

```
  if (e instanceof CustomHttpError) {
        ^

TypeError: Right-hand side of 'instanceof' is not callable
```

Comment: I see no error [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAE2AMwIYFcA28DGnUDOBcAwugTBALYASMMYAolFNHKDMAHYLHOtQ4AbwBQcODghcKUdDkpQAFFGCoEUzAE84AC3pgSEJAC44XdFQBGwKABo4KtRu1VgRVAHNgpmQEsuHgCUwmLicAToYDaKru5egQDcIqHiMDq+BAB0XKiucAC8cADkZBTUdAz80EVJ4gC+Ig0iMFDaoqk6rADuZsA9pZS0+lVKACwATAAM9kWMXDqoXDjAcACaEOiCJKiYVEWJjRKoMDg6cIrAwe1wvsjnK-4Ui8sQdwPlwyzQVykSUgQQTDATKYCAeRTvIaVL5QA71RpAA)

Comment: Do `console.log(require('./lib/src/errors/CustomHttpError'))`. Is the module an object that looks like this? `{ default: [class CustomHttpError] }`

Comment: You should probably be using `import CustomHttpError from './my/path/here'` with typescript.

Comment: @SpenserBlack I'm getting `{ default: [Function: CustomHttpError] }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you're using TypeScript in the main module, instead of `require`, you probably want to do

```js
import CustomHttpError from './lib/src/errors/CustomHttpError';
```

Although you could do

```js
const CustomHttpError = require('./lib/src/errors/CustomHttpError').default;
```

This is happening based on your `tsconfig.json`'s `esModuleInterop` setting. You can read more about it [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#esModuleInterop).

Comment: adding `.default` to the import fixed the error although it's important to mention that to get it working I had to add `Object.setPrototypeOf(this, CustomHttpError.prototype);` to the constructor of my custom error class, too.